# Python/Codacy - Standard pseudo-random generators are not suitable for security/cryptographic purposes

Tags: python, python-3.x, codacy

I have the following code

```
def get_random_date(year_start, year_end):
    return "%s-%s" % (random.randrange(year_start, year_end), random.randrange(1, 12))
```

and I'm getting the warning from [Codacy](https://www.codacy.com/): Standard pseudo-random generators are not suitable for security/cryptographic purposes.

What's should I rewrite this function to avoid such warning.